# Is the ContextObject is ThreadSafe?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**Is ContextObject ThreadSafe? If not, what heppens when I call SubmitChanges in one of the threads?**

What heppens if 2 or more threads use the same `ContextObject` and one of those threads calls `ContextObject.SubmitChanges()` ?

Should I construct a new `ContextObject` to each query to my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `ContextObject` is not thread safe.  The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) details that:

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe.